# Java stream - Sort a List to a HashMap of Lists

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

Let's say I have a `Dog` class.

Inside it I have a `Map<String,String>` and one of the values is `Breed`.

```
public class Dog {
    String id;
    ...
    public Map<String,String>
}
```

I want to get a `Map` of `List`s:

```
HashMap<String, List<Dog>> // breed to a List<Dog>
```

I'd prefer to use a `Stream` rather than iterating it.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You can do it with `groupingBy`.

Assuming that your input is a `List<Dog>`, the `Map` member inside the `Dog` class is called `map`, and the Breed is stored for the "Breed" key :

```
List<Dog> dogs = ...
Map<String, List<Dog>> map = dogs.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> d.map.get("Breed")));
```

Answer (score 81):

The great answer above can further be improved by method reference notation:

```
List<Dog> dogs = ...
Map<String, List<Dog>> map = dogs.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dog::getBreed));
```

Comment: I guess HashMap should be replaced with Map otherwise IDE with lower project language level will report error.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Map<String,Object>> inAppropWords = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> s = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    s.put("type", 1);
    s.put("name", "saas");
    Map<String, Object> s1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    s1.put("type", 2);
    s1.put("name", "swwaas");
    Map<String, Object> s2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    s2.put("type", 1);
    s2.put("name", "saqas");
    inAppropWords.add(s);
    inAppropWords.add(s1);
    inAppropWords.add(s2);
    
    Map<Integer, List<String>> t = inAppropWords.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> AppUtil.getInteger(d.get("type")),Collectors.mapping(d -> String.valueOf(d.get("name")),Collectors.toList())));
    System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: If you want to collect data based on any key and get the corresponding other key values in list